# Pandas Series resample + interpolate gives NaNs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

`x` is a pandas series of float64 numbers on a DateTimeIndex

`x.head(20)` looks like this:

```
Timestamp
2018-05-03 15:05:31.864    1.799104
2018-05-03 15:05:31.993    1.080555
2018-05-03 15:05:32.145    1.374885
2018-05-03 15:05:32.963    1.264249
2018-05-03 15:05:33.529    1.251358
2018-05-03 15:05:33.938    1.199366
2018-05-03 15:05:34.378    1.201764
2018-05-03 15:05:34.496    1.267969
2018-05-03 15:05:34.895    1.251358
2018-05-03 15:05:36.572    1.313922
2018-05-03 15:05:37.562    1.270770
2018-05-03 15:05:38.013    1.230315
2018-05-03 15:05:38.166    1.185131
2018-05-03 15:05:38.285    1.150098
2018-05-03 15:05:39.555    1.122180
2018-05-03 15:05:39.698    1.094660
2018-05-03 15:05:40.815    1.084887
2018-05-03 15:05:41.700    1.068585
2018-05-03 15:05:41.993    1.071981
2018-05-03 15:05:42.139    1.084344
Name: C2:37:A3:40:10:60_s, dtype: float64
```

What I want to do, is to resample and interpolate the series to a 100ms period. This is what I tried:

`y = x.resample("100ms").interpolate("linear")`

It doesn't really do what I expected it to do, at all.

First of all, `y` contains around 100 NaN out of 1700 entries. Shouldn't interpolation take care of the NaNs?

I went ahead and plotted the original `x` series, and the resampled 'y' series.[image: plotted x series (left), y series(right)]

What am I doing wrong? I was really just trying to get a nice and smooth series with values every 100ms, linearly interpolated wherever necessary. Basically turning the left graph into the right graph:

[image: what I have (left), what I want (right)]

I used to do this directly with `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`, but was hoping for something directly in pandas that's less cumbersome to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

You want to interpolate with a union of the existing index along with the resampled index.

```
idx = pd.date_range(x.first_valid_index(), x.last_valid_index(), freq='100ms')
```

This is a cute way of getting the index

```
idx = x.asfreq('100ms').index
```

If you wanted round units of `'100ms'`

```
idx = idx.floor('100ms')
```

---

1. Reindex with unioned index
2. Interpolate with `'index'`.  This will be linear based on space between index values.
3. Reindex again with the reduced `'100ms'`

---

```
y = x.reindex(x.index.union(idx)).interpolate('index').reindex(idx)


y
```

---

```
Timestamp
2018-05-03 15:05:31.864    1.799104
2018-05-03 15:05:31.964    1.242089
2018-05-03 15:05:32.064    1.218038
2018-05-03 15:05:32.164    1.372315
2018-05-03 15:05:32.264    1.358790
2018-05-03 15:05:32.364    1.345265
2018-05-03 15:05:32.464    1.331740
2018-05-03 15:05:32.564    1.318214
2018-05-03 15:05:32.664    1.304689
2018-05-03 15:05:32.764    1.291164
                             ...   
2018-05-03 15:05:41.164    1.078458
2018-05-03 15:05:41.264    1.076616
2018-05-03 15:05:41.364    1.074774
2018-05-03 15:05:41.464    1.072932
2018-05-03 15:05:41.564    1.071090
2018-05-03 15:05:41.664    1.069248
2018-05-03 15:05:41.764    1.069327
2018-05-03 15:05:41.864    1.070486
2018-05-03 15:05:41.964    1.071645
2018-05-03 15:05:42.064    1.077993
Freq: 100L, Name: C2, Length: 103, dtype: float64
```